# Can i copy from one website to localhost

Tags: php, copy, web-crawler

i wrote a crawler that will crawl all the pages in a website and download all the pdf and doc files. Now i want to sort the pdf and doc files as i download. So i tried to create folder and then copy those files in that website. But am not able to copy. Error is that i dont have permission. Is there any alternative to sort and download.

This is how i picked all the link

```
  $original_file    = file_get_contents($link);
                        $stripped_file  = strip_tags($original_file, "<a>");
                        preg_match_all("/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is", $stripped_file, $matches);
                        return $matches['1'];
```

Comment: If you don't have permission to copy files on your __local__ file system you'll need to set these permissions.

BTW: Are you doing something illegal?

Comment: Nothing illegal. They are all freely available pdf. So sorting out the pdf and between the ads is really difficult. So wrote the script. I know about the file permission. But i was wondering if i could download it in folders. Or is there any alternative

Comment: You can only download file by file. It is not impossible to download all contents of a folder at once.

Comment: @SILVINCI THIS IS WRONG,can be done with wget, should be some exaMPLES here in SO

Comment: @itay: wget grabs each individual file. it does not "grab the entire folder".

Comment: @Marc B Why is it important the internal way wget works as opposed to the final result? Might be I am missing something?

Comment: @Itay: because someone'll just try doing `wget http://example.com/somefolder` and expect all files to get downloaded, when it should be `wget -r ...` instead. It's the difference between regurgitating someone's recipe and knowing WHY things are happening. One leads to cargo cult idiocy, the other leads to greater understanding. This site is not just about answering questions, it's here to EDUCATE people as well.

Comment: wow...wget is the perfect solution.